# Set having a enumerable dense subset

Tags: general-topology

I've got an exercise in which I need to prove the following:

> A set has an enumerable dense subset.

Can you share the ways to do this?

Edit:
X a normed vector space
$Y:=B(X,\mathbb{K})$ a vector space over $\mathbb{K}$ of the bounded linear functionals
Show that if $Y$ is separable then $X$ is separable too.

And as I understand all I need is to prove $X$ has a enumerable dense subset, sorry for being late :/

Comment: The existence of a countable dense subset depends on the set and it's topology. Is your set a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ ? Is it a metric space ? This could be of interest to you : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_space

Comment: One way is to define a countable subset and show that it is dense. Another way would be to define a dense subset and show that it is countable. Not much more to be said, given the generality of the question...

Comment: You need to show some details of the exercise, and what you have tried. Otherwise it's impossible to answer, although M.G.2 ha suggested a reference.

Comment: edited sorry for lateness

Answer (score 1):

Note that a discrete space $X$ with $|X|=\frak c$ may not have a countable dense subset.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/633162)

Comment: @Nizar This is a counterexample to the statement that the OP is trying to prove (or at least, what appears to be the statement that the OP is trying to prove).  It certainly belongs in an answer, not a comment.